# Objective C: ADBannerView Change Size and Position

Tags: objective-c, iad, adbannerview

I am trying to implement iAd Banners for my app but i can't seem to do it properly.

I am trying to put an `ADBannerView` in portrait size on my App that is only appearing on landscape but i don't know how to position it right in the center.

Or is there a possible way that i can resize and reposition an `ADBannerView` in landscape? because the Ad is in portrait also (of course) when I clicked the Ad.

Comment: Your app will probably be rejected for this.

Comment: I mean it's possible that you'll be approved but I kind of goes against the GUI paradigm to put a portrait ad on a landscape app, you should probably just use a landscape ad.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle but i can't resize it to smaller size.

Comment: What I'm saying is you should use the landscape ad for a landscape app, it may be wider, but it's thinner, and won't leave gaps on either side.

Answer (score 2):

OK! I found an the answer already!
I used this code for positioning.

```
adBannerView.frame = CGRectOffset(adBannerView.frame, 100, 0);
```