# changing iAd banners position

Tags: ios, xcode, iad, banner

Im struggling to make an iAdBanner appear at the top of the screen instead of the bottom. In the Storyboard I've placed the AdBanner at the top but when the App loads it still appears on the bottom of the screen, however, when I click the Ad and then exit it, the iAdBanner moves to the top of the screen as intended. Any help with getting its default location to the top of the screen is appreciated.

Here is the code that I'm currently using to trigger the add.

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    NSLog(@"Ad Displayed");
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    NSLog(@"Ad Failed To Display");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [AlienGravityGame sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927195/objective-c-adbannerview-change-size-and-position

Comment: adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 100, 0); doesn't affect the position for me at all

Comment: I just create a SK project, add an iAD banner on the top of screen, then copy your bannerViewDidLoadAd: and bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: to my view controller. It's works fine on simulator (iphone/iphone retina).

Comment: I got it fixed, stupid mistake. thanks for the help